# Error in R Markdown: could not find function "split_chain"

Tags: r, r-markdown, magrittr

Hello I am using R markdown and have ran into trouble.

When I try to knit this section of my document (the "example" variable is a data frame with a column called "text" which contains strings):

```
library(qdap)
frequent_terms <- freq_terms(example$text, 4)
frequent_terms
```

I get this error message:

```
Error in split_chain(match.callQ), env = env) :
could not find function "split_chain"
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> %>%
```

I have updated Rstudio and the relevant packages(such as magrittr) but I am still running into this issue, one I have never encountered.

How do I fix this error, or how to I interpret the error message, I am at a loss here. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/issues/238), your problem should be solved if you add `qdap` first, and `magrittr` / `tidyverse` afterward because `gdap` uses an old version of the pipe and masks the most recent `magrittr` version.

However, it is not entirely clear since we do not have a complete reproducible example